# Android unable to focus form fields

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I am completely at a loss here, and because I don't have an Android device, it's been very hard to figure out what's going on, and can't duplicate it in the simulator. For reasons unknown, Chrome on Android is having issues focusing form fields, and users are starting to complain. Everything works fine on other platforms - including Chrome on Windows/Mac/iOS.

The site having the problems is no longer broken, as the problem was resolved.

Any guidance would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I suspect they're being "covered up" by the vimeo video player iframe. Although it's set to visibility:hidden, it seems to still reserve space in its normal location. When the forms are opened, the vimeo iframe is on top of them, it's just invisible. Maybe when people are tapping on form elements, android is thinking it's a tap on the iframe. I'm not 100% sure yet, but an easy way to test would be to set the iframe to display:none, as well as visibility:hidden, which stops it from reserving space for itself. When the iframe is made visible, you can also set display:block temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimeo iframe is taking the focus, hence the input fields are not clickable.

Set the width and padding-top to the modal containing Vimeo iframe only when the modal is selected.

Change following css selector :

```
.modal .modal-inner.modal-video {
    width: 90% !important;
    padding-top: 50.625%;
}
```

to

```
.modal .modal-state:checked+.modal-window .modal-inner.modal-video {
    width: 90% !important;
    padding-top: 50.625%;
}
```

Comment: @TimSullivan I've added gif version of screen record for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing locally and confirmed that my comment is correct. If you set the vimeo iframe to display: none; that will allow the form elements to be tapped on android / chrome. So you'll need to make three changes:

1. css update: set vimeo iframe to display: none
2. javascript update - where you normally set vimeo's iframe to visibility:visible, you'll also have to set display:block
3. javascript update - similar to above, where you set vimeo's iframe to visibility:hidden, you'll also have to set display: none

I believe that will solve the problem and have no negative side effects.

Answer (score 0):

That website is very laggy on my device, perhaps you should reconsider the design. Or make it simpler for tablets/phones.

Nevertheless I found that text fields that follow (including) "*What are your three favourite movies?*" can be focused properly, and it seems there's some view on top of the first text fields in this form.

Perhaps that can lead you in the right direction. Good luck!